# How to have awk print variable instead of the full matched line?

Tags: awk

The awk script below prints a different result than expected, and I'd like to know why. How can I make it behave the way I want?

#### Awk script

```
$ cat script.awk 
/^This is/ {
    print "Block entered";

    my_var="value";
    print $my_var;
};
```

#### Input data

```
$ cat input-data 
This is the text to match
```

#### Expected output

```
Block entered
value
```

#### Actual output

```
$ awk -f script.awk -- input-data 
Block entered
This is the text to match
```

Comment: It should be `print my_var` without `$`

Comment: The symbol `$` is called a sigil -- a [symbol of magical powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil)! To remove the magic, remove the sigil.

Comment: @anubhava thanks, that worked. If you provide your comment as answer I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: Found out this question already [existed at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291126/why-does-awk-print-the-whole-line-when-i-want-it-to-print-a-variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anubhava's already suggested a fix for OP's code; the following is an explanation of what OP's code is doing ...

`$` is used to reference a field in the current line (eg, `$1` == 1st field) so ...

`$myvar` becomes `$value`, but since this is an invalid field reference `awk` silently ignores it so ...

`print $myvar` becomes `print` but ...

`print` (with no args) says to print the current (input) line ...

hence the output of `This is the text to match`

**NOTE:** following the link provided by OP (see comment - above), it appears that `$value` may actually be treated as `$0` leaving us with `print $0` (which is the same as `print` in this case)

---

Consider:

```
awk '{myvar="1"; print $myvar}' <<< "field#1 field#2 field#3"
```

In this scenario `$myvar` becomes `$1` which **is** a valid field reference so the output generated is:

```
field#1
```

Comment: This provides quite some additional information compared to Anubhavas comment, hence I'm happy to accept.